# Randomly thrown exception: TypeInitializationException (involving Unity Container)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, appdomain

This is a very weird issue to me. The point is I cannot reproduce the exception in local environment (where I have full source code to run debugging, the connection is still a live one from remote location).

I have an interface called `IDataAccess` used to access all sql data used in all my Controllers. So I intended to use a singleton here.
The problem is I also use Unity Container to inject that instance (as dependency) into my controller. Here is one controller using that interface:

```
public AccountController(IDataAccess da){
   DataAccess = da;
}
//this instance is used inside the controller
public IDataAccess DataAccess {get;set;}
```

And here is how I configure the Unity Container, I have a separate class like this:

```
public class UnityContainerConfig
{
    public static IUnityContainer Uc { get; private set; }
    public static void LoadDependencies(IUnityContainer uc = null)
    {
        Uc = uc ?? new UnityContainer();
        Uc.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
        //some other not-related registration here 
        Uc.RegisterType<IDataAccess, DataAccess>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), 
             new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), 
             new InterceptionBehavior<UserInfoCacheInterceptionBehavior>(), 
             new InjectionConstructor(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnection"].ConnectionString,
                                      WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["loginConnection"].ConnectionString),
             new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>()
          );
       //other registrations ...
    }
}
```

Finally I call the `LoadDependencies` in `UnityConfig.LoadComponents` (I also used `Unity.Mvc5` to integrate Unity with MVC), like this:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        UnityContainerConfig.LoadDependencies(container);            
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

The `RegisterComponents()` is called in the right place in `Application_Start`.

So as you can see I have an implementation for `IDataAccess` called `DataAccess`. This has one constructor accepting 2 strings (2 connection strings) (and these are injected by using `InjectionConstructor`). I also add some interceptions to intercept the `IDataAccess` for logging and caching (I think that part should not be involved here).

And here is the randomly thrown exception (I copied this from the logged text):

> 6/5/2017 8:40:55 AM - Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
>      at .cctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IDataAccess_bf33a9ed4f92418083f514de204b5b2a.CheckLogin(String userName, String password)
>      at AsmChecklistSite.ApplicationSignInManager.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at AsmChecklistSite.Controllers.AccountController.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

That happened on logging in, the call to `CheckLogin` which is called inside the `Login` action method of the `AccountController`.

The `CheckLogin` is just simple like this:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckLogin(string userName, string password)
{            
     password = SomeUtil.Encode(password);
     using(var con = new SqlConnection(LoginConnectionString))
     {                
        var i = con.ExecuteScalar<int>("select count(1) from Users where username=@u and password=@p", new { u = userName, p = password });
        return i > 0;
     }
}
```

Here I use `Dapper` (as the DAL, it extends the IDbConnection so I can use the extension method `ExecuteScalar` on an instance of connection).

As I said before I cannot reproduce this on my local environment. Only after publishing the site to my server, the exception is thrown randomly. Sometimes I can log-in OK and even trying many times after that. But sometimes it fails with the exception (and once it is failed, multiple attempts tried right after that would still fail). Then at some time later, I may still log-in OK again. That's really weird.

I've run out of ideas on how this could happen. The Unity Container should be singleton (it's held by a static instance in `UnityContainerConfig` class, also it's wrapped by `UnityDependencyResolver` which is managed by the singleton `DependencyResolver.Current`). The `IDataAccess` is also registered using `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`. So I would expect that its instance is a singleton and persistent? Still I'm not sure about the actual meaning of the exception message (so it may not actually involve the IDataAccess?)

Comment: Why do you think the interception part "should not be involved here"? If you look at the stack trace, there is a clean indication that this actually has to do with interception, considering the exception originates from a dynamically generated proxy class for `IDataAccess`, namely `Wrapped_IDataAccess_bf33a9ed4f92418083f514de204b5b2a`. This is something that Unity does. This might be a concurrency bug in Unity. To bad it isn't maintained anymore.

Comment: @Steven thank you for your response. I thought so just because I don't see it clearly in the stacktrace. It looks like to me that the `IDataAccess` is what existed in the unloaded Appdomain. So you implicitly suggested that I should try removing the interceptions to see if it's working? Well in fact I still keep those interceptions and the website now does not fault easily as before. I mean I hardly could reproduce the exception here even for the published site (in fact not any reproduced yet).

Comment: @Steven What I changed to my code is just changing the log path (the `LoggingInterceptionBehavior` and one more custom `HandleErrorAttribute` provide the logging feature together). The issue is the log file path I used before is inside the ASP.NET application folder (the bin folder). And writing to the file there made the site extremely slow on each request. I change the log file path to the outside folder and that performance issue has gone now. The original issue I asked here seems also to be vanished as well (not sure but at least I have not reproduced any yet).